# AngularJS Return a promise inside a event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've a `$routeChangeSuccess` event inside a `run` function. I like to load something with `$http` than change the `$template`. The problem is that `$http` is asynchronous. I've tried to return a promise inside the event. Without success. Is it possible or do i need to use jquery directly to load my resource without `$http`.

```
app.run(["$rootScope", "$http", "$location", "$q", "localize", function($rootScope, $http, $location, $q) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, current, previous) {
        var promise = $q.defer();
        //load something and resolve promise when everything is ready
        return promise;
    });
}
]);
```

Comment: if you're going to return a promise anyway, why not return the promise from $http?

Comment: because i've more logic to handle

Comment: if you have more logic to handle, attach more .then()s on your original promise. Each then() will return a new promise object with the processed results in its data.

Answer (score 3):

The $q.defer method does not return a promise. It returns a deferred object. You need to return deferred.promise to return the promise.

Change your code to

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // load something and resolve promise when everything is ready
    // resolve it using deferred.resolve('foo');
    return deferred.promise;
```

Read the docs http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Comment: just written here. not in orginal.

Comment: can you please add a plunker to describe the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, current, previous) {
    return $http.get(some_url)
        .success(function(data){
            // do something with the data
            return myChangedData;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            // do something on error, $broadcast?
            return myError;
        });
});
```

Comment: it will not block the next calls inside angularJS. Setting a property like "current.locals.$template" is not possible inside the $http callback. I've done this with jquery right now.

Comment: Take a look at $http interceptors (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)  "For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept requests before they are handed to the server and responses before they are handed over to the application code"